# Find source na replacement parameters in a string and perform replacement in another string

Tags: oracle, function, replace, plsql, regexp-replace

I need a function that applies a certain rule to replace words in a string.

There are two variables:

- v_imp_user_list - list of users delimited by pipe (example: JOHN|PETER|MARK|USER_PROD)
- v_schema_remap_list - list of users that should be remapped (old value - new value, example: JOHN-GEORGE,USER_PROD-USER_TEST)

The function should parse v_schema_remap_list variable and if the name of the first user (before dash, old value) 
exist in v_imp_user_list then replace it with the second user (after dash, new value).

Example:

v_imp_user_list := '**JOHN**|PETER|MARK|**USER_PROD**'

v_schema_remap_list := '**JOHN-GEORGE**,**USER_PROD-USER_TEST**'

Desired outcome:
**GEORGE**|PETER|MARK|**USER_TEST**

I have a solution which I will post but for some reason I don't like it and will appreciate any comment/review/better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This function helps me to parse the v_schema_remap_list.

```
  --    extract nth occurence in a delimited string
        create or replace function f_find_str (
            source_string varchar2
            , occurence_outer number --occurence of the old-new pair
            , occurence_inner number --old/new value, enter 1 for old or 2 for new
            )
        return varchar2
        is
            v_aux varchar2(500);
            v_result varchar2(100);
        begin
            v_aux := ltrim(regexp_substr(',' || source_string, ',[^,]*', 1, occurence_outer),',');
            if occurence_inner = 1 then
                v_result := substr(v_aux, 1, instr(v_aux, '-')-1);
            elsif occurence_inner = 2 then
                v_result := substr(v_aux, instr(v_aux, '-')+1);
            end if;
            return v_result;
        end;
        /
```

This anonymous block shows my solution (see the loop inside).

```
    declare
     v_schema_remap_list varchar2(1000) := 'JOHN-GEORGE,USER_PROD-USER_TEST';
     v_imp_user_list varchar2(1000) := 'JOHN|PETER|MARK|USER_PROD';
     v_schema_remap_cnt number := nvl(regexp_count(v_schema_remap_list, '-'), 0); 
    begin

        for i in 1..v_schema_remap_cnt
        loop
            v_imp_user_list := replace(
                v_imp_user_list||'|', 
                f_find_str (
                source_string => v_schema_remap_list
                , occurence_outer => i
                , occurence_inner => 1
                )||'|', 
                f_find_str (
                source_string => v_schema_remap_list
                , occurence_outer => i
                , occurence_inner => 2
                )||'|'
            );
            v_imp_user_list := rtrim(v_imp_user_list, '|');
        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_imp_user_list); --test output
    end;
    /
```